# how to create ascii art in python

Tags: python

How do i make big letters via numbers in python, like metasploit written in console? [like this metasploit structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7AfY.png)

Comment: That's an ascii art, so i guess, write yours ([here's some examples](http://www.ascii-fr.com/)) also please look at this : [How do I ask a good question ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. unfortunatly, it is a question for a search engine, not for SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can try the [`art`](https://pypi.org/project/art/) package for python

example:

```
>>> from art import *
>>> Art=text2art("art") # Return ascii text (default font) and default chr_ignore=True 
>>> print(Art)
              _   
  __ _  _ __ | |_ 
 / _` || '__|| __|
| (_| || |   | |_ 
 \__,_||_|    \__|
```

[image]